# how to change the from attribute to my email in mail() function

Tags: php, function, email

I am trying to send an email to my customers when they place an order on my website. But the from appears like this: 
From : n9da2313
I need to exchange it with info@awraq.me
I tried this but didn't work
`

```
            $to = "founder@awraq.me";
            $subject = "Your order";
            $message = "Your order was placed successfuly";
            $headers = "From: info@awraq.me";
            $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: info@awraq.me";
            $headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f info@awraq.me");
        `
```

Comment: Depending on your mail system, when you add an email as a contact, it only shows the name you've defined. Have you tried to put the `founder@awraq.me` or another mail as the sender to check?

Comment: yes I tried to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this-

```
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

If its not working then check if you have done some configuration in php.ini file.

Comment: It's not working. What kind of configuration in php.ini can lead to this?